# Fill an empty stack with sorted String values

Tags: java, stack, structure

I have an array of string values (unsorted). And my goal is to sort those values and then  push()  them into an empty stack. The problem that I cannot solve is that when I push() the string with the lowest character into my stack, I can't find the way to remove that string so that the next time my loop iterates, that string wont be compared again with the next lowest. I know I may be going through the wrong approach, but I think it is a good way to practice for my Data structure class.here is my code:

```
import java.util.*;

public class StackClass {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Stack<String> name = new Stack<String>();
        String arr[] = {"Camila",  "Zury", "Diego",
        "Gabriela","Brian","Fabian", "Harry","Martin", "Luis", "Anderson",};    
        String minChar;
        minChar= arr[0];
        for (int i = 1; i < arr.length; i++) {  
            if(arr[i].charAt(0) < minChar.charAt(0)) {// to compare the lowest char    
                minChar = arr[i]; //lowest char = minChar   
            }
        }
        name.push(minChar); //minChar is pushed into the stack.
        System.out.println(name);
    }
}
```

Comment: `Arrays.asList(arr).stream().sorted().forEachOrdered(name::add);`

Answer (score 0):

If you were to use an array list of string ( `ArrayList<String>` ), you could simply use the `remove(item)` function, as ArrayLists support dynamic sizing.

Unfortunately arrays are of fixed length, so an option for your case is to remove the object reference of `arr[i]` . eg

```
if(arr[i].charAt(0) < minChar.charAt(0)) {// to compare the lowest char    
            minChar = arr[i]; //lowest char = minChar 
            arr[i] = null; //this will remove the object reference but not resize the array  
        }
```

Comment: This will not work properly. Setting `arr[i]` to null should be done after the `for` loop ends.

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    String names[] = { "Peter", "Patricia", "Hunter", "Sarah",
            "Gabe", "Gina", "Rob", "John", "Zoey", "Tammy", "Robert",
            "Sean", "Paschal", "Kathy", "Nill", "Val" };
    Stack<String> stack = new Stack<>();

    Arrays.sort(names); 

    for (String name: names) {
        stack.push(name);
    }

    //test
    for (String name: stack) {
        System.out.println(name);
    }
}
```